# Android ImagePicker/MediaStore returns rotated image

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, exif, mediastore

I know this question has been asked many times but there is no best-case answer to be found.

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri)
```

I am retrieving the bitmap from this code, it returns a rotated bitmap. Also, the Uri which I am passing is in the form of `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A3553763`

I can't use **ExifInterface** because it requires a real path from uri but the URI which I have can't be converted to a real path. I already tried a few answers which some of which work up to some extent and return but they fail if I pick an image from the MIUI gallery or the System storage app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround that solved the problem at last. So the thing is to actually create a temporary file in the **cacheDir** or anywhere else. After that, we can easily get the real path of this image file and can perform Exif to rotate the image.

*You may wonder why doing it the hard way when the ExifInterface supports inputStream?*

That's because ExifInterface was always returning me **0** for orientation even though the image needed rotation.

So here is the code which helped me achieve the solution.

```
fun getFilePathFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri, uniqueName: Boolean): String =
    if (uri.path?.contains("file://") == true) {
        uri.path!!
    } else {
        getFileFromContentUri(context, uri, uniqueName).path
    }

private fun getFileFromContentUri(context: Context, contentUri: Uri, uniqueName: Boolean): File {
    // Preparing Temp file name
    val fileExtension = getFileExtension(context, contentUri) ?: ""
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", getDefault()).format(Date())
    val fileName = ("temp_file_" + if (uniqueName) timeStamp else "") + ".$fileExtension"
    // Creating Temp file
    val tempFile = File(context.cacheDir, fileName)
    tempFile.createNewFile()
    // Initialize streams
    var oStream: FileOutputStream? = null
    var inputStream: InputStream? = null

    try {
        oStream = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
        inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)

        inputStream?.let { copy(inputStream, oStream) }
        oStream.flush()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        // Close streams
        inputStream?.close()
        oStream?.close()
    }

    return tempFile
}

private fun getFileExtension(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? =
    if (uri.scheme == ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT) {
        MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(context.contentResolver.getType(uri))
    } else {
        uri.path?.let { MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(File(it)).toString()) }
    }

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun copy(source: InputStream, target: OutputStream) {
    val buf = ByteArray(8192)
    var length: Int
    while (source.read(buf).also { length = it } > 0) {
        target.write(buf, 0, length)
    }
}
```

After that, I just called the method `getFilePathFromUri` into my ExifProcessingMethod (for rotating/flipping bitmap) if needed!

```
var bmp = SendCapturedImageActivity.retrieveBitmapFromFile(
            File(GetFilePathFromUri().getFilePathFromUri(applicationContext, uri, false))
        )
```

Now this above bitmap is absolutely correct in orientation.
I hope this help anyone who has this issue <3

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use ExifInterface because it requires a real path from uri

It has not needed that in several years. Specifically, use [the `ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface) from [the `androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface` artifact](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/exifinterface). It has [a constructor that accepts an `InputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream)), and you can get an `InputStream` for the content associated with your `Uri` via `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`.

Also, FWIW, many image loading libraries automatically handle the image rotation for you.